# How to make schema changes while preserving data when using database project in visual studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, database-project, dacpac

Last year we had imported the database into a visual studio database project.

Subsequent db schema changes (like changing of data type, adding new tables, columns) were made offline in the visual studio database project and then the changes were published back into the production database using the **dacpac** file.

This approach gave us way to version control (add to source control) the database changes.

Now I am facing a challenge when dealing with a task that involves changing schema and data. The following is the explanation of change needed:

Existing table-

Claims: ClaimID ContractID ClaimTitle ClaimantName ClaimantNI ClaimantAddress ClaimDate SettleDate ClaimAmt SettleAmt

A car accident claim usually meant 1 record (claimant) in the database. The business is changing the process and wants to allow multiple claimants for same claim. So the new structure proposed is:

Claim: **ClaimID** ContractID ClaimTitle ClaimDate SettleDate ClaimAmt SettleAmt

Matter: MatterID **ClaimID** ClaimantName ClaimantNI ClaimantAddress

The existing claim table has data. So if I delete the columns (ClaimantName, ClaimantNI, ClaimantAddress) from the table and create a new table for those columns (as per the above schema), then I loose the data.

If not for the visual studio database project approach, then I would have connected to SQL server via SSMS, taken the database backup, create the new *Matter* table, write sql query to Insert records from the *Claim* table into the *Matter* table, delete the 3 columns from the *Claim* table.

What is the approach to make such changes when working with **dacpac** file in visual studio database project?

There is possibility to use the pre-deploy and post-deploy scripts. I cannot use pre-deploy as the new table isn't available at that point. And post-deploy script approach won't work as by then the deployment will have removed the columns from the `Claim` table.

Comment: Aren't you using a decent ORM library? It should support versioning and so have hooks you can supply for upgrading and downgrading between database versions - just invoke the SQL code in there that you'd run from SSMS.

Comment: We use Entity framework for ORM. With the database project we use the dacpac deployment approach. And not the EF migrations. Which is the place I can invoke the SQL code that I'd otherwise run via SSMS?

Comment: If I had to do this in dacpacs, I'd create the new structures, then migrate the data in a post-deploy script. Next release - rename/move tables around as appropriate. I might even put them into a new schema.  This isn't a change I'd make as a "change these tables directly" within a state-based tool like SSDT.

Comment: `If I had to do this in dacpacs, I'd create the new structures, then migrate the data in a post-deploy script. Next release - rename/move tables around as appropriate.` - this makes sense. What do you mean by `I might even put them into a new schema. This isn't a change I'd make as a "change these tables directly" within a state-based tool like SSDT.` please?